# How to convert a String array to List?

Tags: java

I have a Java project witch consults an API which returns a `String` like:

```
"['test1', 'test2', 'test3']" // the array is a string
```

So basically an array object parsed to a `String`. I would like to know the best way to convert it to a real Java `List`.

Comment: Since that string looks like Json I suggest using a Json parser. There are a lot of libraries out there that you could use.

Comment: sorry, the "array" is a string itself

Comment: @Thomas it is similar to JSON, but it is not JSON.

Comment: JSON requires double quotes, so the single quotes would first have to be replaced. You'd need to be sure your values never contain any actual double quotes, though.

Comment: There is not enough information here to make a recommendation. What you have is an example, and you need a *definition*. Are the substrings always between single quotes? Is there allowance for empty strings, or empty arrays? Are the elements always strings? Are there escape characters to process? This are just the questions I came up with off the top of my head, no doubt if I spent 5 minutes or longer I could come up with more. You need a definition before you can decide. I am assuming you have no control over what is returned from the API, so you have to know how they've defined it.

Comment: @Henry, granted it's not in the standard definition of Json but almost all Json parsers I know of support single quotes for strings and thus could be considered a defacto standard. Even if not, I wrote "it looks like Json" not "it is Json" ;D

Answer (score 5):

`['test1', 'test2', 'test3']` is a JSON array so it can be parsed with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Although JSON usually mandates using double quotes around `String` values, Gson will still parse single quotes:

```
String json = "['test1', 'test2', 'test3']";
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
System.out.println(list); // [test1, test2, test3]
```

Alternatively you could use a regular expression. Assuming that values can't contain escaped apostrophe `\'` symbol:

```
String text = "['test1', 'test2', 'test3']";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'([^']+)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    list.add(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println(list); // [test1, test2, test3]
```